# Is there a packages to estimate Diebold-Li Parameters in R?

Tags: interest-rates

"The models implemented are: Nelson-Siegel, Diebold-Li and Svensson" is written in the description of the packages "YieldCurve". However, I can't find a specific estimation function for the diebold-li parameters. How can I fix this problem with this packages or do you know other packages for the estimation?

Comment: Can't you use that package along with the "vars" package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diebold/Li is not a separate yield-curve model: for a given cross-section of
yields, they fix the shape parameter in Nelson-Siegel and then estimate the remaining parameters via linear regression. See [Calibrating the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson Model](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1676747).
The function `NSf` in package in package [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF), which I maintain, sets up the factor loadings for Nelson-Siegel, as used by Diebold/Li.